# Función escalar ROUND con SQL Server y Oracle con FireDAC

Tags: sql-server, delphi, oracle-19c

Me encuentro trabajando con una versión XE7 de Delphi con conexión a Oracle y SQL Server, estoy implementando funciones escalares para ambos, y una de ellas es ROUND, cuando realizo pruebas directamente en cada manejador obtengo los mismos resultados pero cuando probre ROUND desde un proyecto de Delphi obtengo tipos de datos distintos y el resultado varía, no es el mismo en ambos manejadores, un ejemplo a continuación:

```
Valor de FDQuery en Delphi:
SELECT ROUND(CINCO,-2) FROM PRUEBAS;

Prueba con SQL Server
Tipo de dato en la columna en SQL Server = MONEY
Tipo de dato obtenido en Delphi después de realizar la consulta = ftCurrency

Prueba con Oracle
Tipo de dato en la columna en Oracle = NUMBER(19,4)
Tipo de dato obtenido en Delphi después de realizar la consulta = ftFMTBcd
```

En Oracle sin importar el tipo de dato de la columna siempre obtengo un tipo de dato en delphi de ftFMTBcd, en cambio con SQL Server va variando dependiendo del tipo de dato que sea la columna, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los tipos de datos también se respeten para Oracle y obtenga los mismos que en SQL Server? espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias

Comment: ¿En qué te afecta que el tipo de dato a nivel de base de datos sea distinto? ¿En qué te afecta que el tipo de dato del `TField` que representa a la columna en Delphi sea distinto? Pregunto, porque sospecho que podemos encontrarnos ante un [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/21).

Comment: En la manera en que lo muestra al aplicarle un .value, debido a que delphi los maneja distinto y a pesar de que los manejadores me devuelven el mismo resultado delphi me los muestra distintos

Comment: No comprendo qué quieres decir con que _"Delphi te los muestra distintos"_. En realidad no veo mayor inconveniente en que los tipos de dato sean diferentes.

Comment: Con un tipo de dato float(53) en SQL Server y el equivalente en oracle que es float(49), cuando realizo el ROUND delphi en pantalla me muestra 1254875212365490000000000000 y es un tipo de dato ftFMTBcd, en cambio con SQL Server delphi me muestra en pantalla 1.25487521236549E27 y es un tipo de dato ftFloat, a eso me refiero que son distintos, sé que son valores equivalentes, pero yo necesito obtener el mismo resultado en pantalla que en SQL Server

Comment: Ya intente con las Map Rules pero revisando la precisión del dato que me llega siempre es 38, no varía y no sé como podría identificar los diferentes tipos de datos

Comment: Si quieres que ambos luzcan iguales, coloca algún valor que haga sentido en la propiedad `DisplayFormat` del `TField` asociado al campo.

Comment: He revisado más a fondo el código y verifique que no es problema con el componente de FireDAC sino que desde Oracle el tipo de dato que devuelve la función ROUND siempre es un integer (number(38)), ¿sabes de alguna manera de controlar este tipo de dato que devuelve Oracle aparte de aplicar un convert explícito?

Comment: Quizás Oracle está eligiendo ese tipo de dato porque el round no tiene decimales. Eché un ojo a la documentación y no me quedó claro, pero yo probaría hacer un round con decimales, solo para ver que devuelve, por ejemplo `round(midato, 2)` y `round(round(midato, -2), 2)`, aunque sospecho que el último va a devolver entero, ¿qué devuelve el primero?.  Otra cosa que no me queda clara es por qué no quieres aplicar un convert explícito?